# Is it good practice to set a variable equal to your entire database?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, database

I'm assuming that this answer varies based on how big the database is. However, assuming that the database is pretty big, maybe 0.5 GB to 5 GB, would it be good practice to query the database whenever a task is invoked rather than to set a variable equal to the entire database at script launch and search through the variable instead of the database?

What I was doing before was:

Whenever the server was launched, it would query the entire database and set a variable equal to the collection. Whenever there was a new "row" (not sure what they call it in MongoDB) of data, it would be pushed to the variable AND the database. If the "row" existed, it would $set whatever data it needed to the DB and variable.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's called `caching` and depends on what your app does. If it's just a small app with small amount of data, you can just query the database

Comment: I thought that it would be bad to "cache" data if it's in large quantities. Wouldn't that take more RAM?

Comment: It's not a good idea to cache all data. Usually you identify the data that is used frequently and cache it. But it all depends on the app and hardware you have (there are distributed caching solutions, for example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  And don't worry about introducing any caching until you have an actual performance problem you can trace back to a specific query taking too long.

MongoDB performs its own caching of recently accessed indexes and documents, so it's typically redundant to do any general-purpose caching of your own.

See [the FAQ](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/fundamentals/#does-mongodb-require-a-separate-caching-layer-for-application-level-caching) for more info on the topic.